# How to check If column exists and table row count togather before running the query in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, procedure

I need to execute one query, Before executing the query I need to check the following two conditions,
1) Table row count is 0
2) One of table column exists.

So basing on my requirement I wrote the procedure as follows,

```
DECLARE
   rowCount INT;
   column_not_exists exception;
   pragma exception_init (column_not_exists , -00904);
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) INTO rowCount FROM Settings;
IF (rowCount = 0) THEN
Insert into Settings (ID,PROCESSID,AREA) select ID,PROCESSID,AREA from POINT WHERE CLASSNAME = 'ENDPOINT' and PROCESSID IS NOT NULL;
END IF;
exception WHEN column_not_exists THEN NULL;
END;
/
```

But somehow the exception is not handled and still I can see the error message in the logs

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PROCESSID": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Can somebody help me here to validate both the conditions togather.

Comment: About row count you can use dba_tab_statistics (it shows statistics about table from last database gather statistics, if close row count is important it isn't suitable ). about column you can query a table's column from dba_tab_columns and check existence of column there.

Comment: can you expand your Point(table) structure from your database!!!

Comment: ora-00904 is a compile-time exception. Exception section traps run-time exceptions. Putting it simply, ora-00904 cannot be trapped for static SQL- it can be trapped for dynamic SQL, though. It doesn't make any sense to handle that exception for a static SQL, anyway. You should know the structure of a table you are inserting/selecting data into/from.

Answer (score 0):

You had better use system view ALL_TAB_COLUMNS (of course, you need to have priveleges to access it). Also you need to use Oracle dynamic SQL statement "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE", otherwise your code will not compile.

I've altered you code here, please replace accordingly these places:
 lower(t.OWNER)='owner',
 lower(t.TABLE_NAME)='point'

code:

```
declare
  rowcount int;
  l_cnt number;
begin
  select count(*) into rowcount from settings;
  if (rowcount = 0) then
   select count(*) into l_cnt from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS t
             where lower(t.OWNER)='owner' and lower(t.TABLE_NAME)='point'
             and lower(t.COLUMN_NAME) in ('processid','area');
     if l_cnt = 2  then
      execute immediate 'insert into settings
        (id, processid, area)
        select id, processid, area
          from point
         where classname = ''ENDPOINT''
           and processid is not null';
    end if;
  end if;

end;
```

Comment: Just a note: no permissions are required for ALL_TAB_COLS. You automatically have access to it, it is DBA_TAB_COLS for which you need permission.

USER_TAB_COLS includes all tables and views which you own, there is no OWNER column.

ALL_TAB_COLS includes all tables and views to which you have access, including tables in other schemas. Because of this, there is an OWNER column.

DBA_TAB_COLS includes all tables and views  in the database.